Preceding rows sum and subtraction using SQL
I have the following dataset which I'm trying to create SQL to generate the FEE column.



CUSTOMER
YEAR
MONTH
REVENUE
FEE
NOTES




CUSTOMER A
FY24
1
0
0



CUSTOMER A
FY24
2
0
0



CUSTOMER A
FY24
3
0
0



CUSTOMER A
FY24
4
0
0



CUSTOMER A
FY24
5
0
0



CUSTOMER A
FY24
6
0
0



CUSTOMER A
FY24
7
5000
5000
FEE = REVENUE - SUM(ALL PRECEDING ROWS FOR FEES COLUMN FOR CUSTOMER AND YEAR) or 0


CUSTOMER A
FY24
8
0
0



CUSTOMER A
FY24
9
7000
2000
FEE = REVENUE - SUM(ALL PRECEDING ROWS FOR FEES COLUMN FOR CUSTOMER AND YEAR) or 5000


CUSTOMER A
FY24
10
150000
143000
FEE = REVENUE - SUM(ALL PRECEDING ROWS FOR FEES COLUMN FOR CUSTOMER AND YEAR) or 7000


CUSTOMER A
FY24
11
0
0



CUSTOMER A
FY24
12
0
0




I have tried a combination of window analytical functions however I can't seem to get to end result which is detailed above. Can anyone help with what SQL statement I can use to calculate the FEES column?
Thank you

PROCEEDING ROWS - according to what order? (The above tables looks unordered.)

@jarlh apologies I meant to say preceding not proceeding. Also the order of the fiscal year and month.

No problem, spelling wasn't the issue. Fiscal year and month was what I was asking for. But do you really store month name, not month number?

@jarlh I do store the number maybe it is better to put that in instead of the string. I have updated it.

Shouldn't 143000 be 1380000? (150000 - 7000 - 5000)

@jarlh No. It’s based off what FEE has already been calculated. This is the tricky part.

There are two kind of rows:

those with a revenue = zero where you want a fee of zero
those with a revenue != zero where you want a calculation

You can use two queries for these, glueing the results with UNION ALL.
The calculation involves a window function as you already know. That window function is LAG, because you want the fee to be "this revenue minus last revenue".
SELECT customer, year, month, revenue, 0 as fee
FROM mytable
WHERE revenue = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT
  customer, year, month, revenue,
  revenue - COALESCE(LAG(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY year, month), 0) AS fee
FROM mytable
WHERE revenue <> 0
ORDER BY customer, year, month;

If you really want to start each year anew, then you'd make this: PARTITION BY customer, year ORDER BY month.

It seems FEE = (REVENUE - preceding REVENUE) due to your recursive formula.
Provided REVENUE is growing only you can use MAX with a propriate window to get the preceding REVENUE.
select t.*,  
        case when revenue > 0
           then revenue - max(revenue) over (partition by CUSTOMER order by YEAR, MONTH rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
        else 0
    end fee
from t


To do it in 1 table scan (avoiding the UNION) and supporting negative revenue (the solution with MAX() doesn't), you need a system supporting "LAST_VALUE() IGNORE NULLS" analytic, then:
select d.*,
    case when revenue <> 0 then 
        revenue - coalesce(last_value(decode(revenue,0, cast(null as <<REVENUE DATA TYPE>>), revenue) ignore nulls) 
            over(partition by customer, year order by month
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),0)
    else 0 end as fee
from data d
;

Seems Snowflake does https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_value ...
